# ESRI layer showing on one machine but not another

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

When I run the code below on my machine, there is no street information shown:

[image: empty map]

However, when I run the exact same code on a different machine, the map successfully loads:

[image: correct map]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lat_min = 39.714223
lat_max = 39.790
long_min= -105.184
long_max = -104.962

m= Basemap(llcrnrlon=long_min, llcrnrlat=lat_min, urcrnrlon=long_max, urcrnrlat=lat_max, lat_0=(lat_max - lat_min)/2, lon_0=(long_max-long_min)/2, projection='merc', epsg=4326, resolution = 'c', area_thresh=10000.,)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.drawmapboundary()

m.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D', xpixels=2000, verbose=True, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

Are there extra import steps beyond installing Basemap that are necessary to show  ESRI layers? I installed Basemap on the machine where the script is functioning several months ago, and I can't remember if there were any additional steps required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `drawmapboundary()` which, by default, fills the map with the `Axes` background color. Either leaving the command out or setting the fill color to `'none'` will solve the problem. I.e. the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lat_min = 39.714223
lat_max = 39.790
long_min= -105.184
long_max = -104.962

m= Basemap(
    llcrnrlon=long_min, llcrnrlat=lat_min,
    urcrnrlon=long_max, urcrnrlat=lat_max,
    ##lat_0=(lat_max + lat_min)/2,
    ##lon_0=(long_max+long_min)/2,
    projection='merc',
    epsg=4326,
    resolution = 'c',
    area_thresh=10000.,
)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='none')

m.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D', xpixels=2000, verbose=True, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

Produces this image for me:

[image: result of the above code]

Without the `fill_color='none'` I get a white map as well. Hope this helps.